# Writing a non-blocking programs

Tags: java, nonblocking

I understand that its really difficult to write non-blocking(lock free) programs. Still what all things you must take care of while writing one in Java using the basic building blocks i.e. CAS operation.

-- Edit --

If I have shared resources and I do not want to lock the shared resources, instead would want to use compareAndSet(expectedValue, valueToSet) instruction probably in a while loop until I succeed. In java we have AtomicXXX classes that support this operation. For example write a non-blocking stack Refer(Java Concurrency in Practice)

What all things I would need to keep in my mind, what all test scenarios can be there..

Comment: Do you have any specific question?

Comment: If you want a non-blocking program don't have shared resources.

Comment: If I have shared resources and I do not want to lock the shared resources, instead would want to use compareAndSet(expectedValue, valueToSet) instruction probably in a while loop until I succeed. In java we have AtomicXXX classes that support this operation. For example write a non-blocking stack Refer(Java Concurrency in Practice)

Answer (score 3):

The main difficulty with lock-free programming is on an architectural level. You need to design your code and your algorithms in a way, that they do not interfere with each other's data. You need to "block" your code in individual tasks that can be run separately and especially independently. Once you've been diving into those ideas however, you start to wonder why you used so much blocking before.

Example: Given is an array of sentences and you want to count the words in each one, and you want to do it in a threaded way.

First you need to pin-point the "choke-points", that is where the threads could potentially clash. In this case the data-source (the array) and the data-output which is the counting and the final println of the result. So you need to find a way how to do this without synchronizing or locking on those data sources. Lucky for you Java offers the Atomics classes, which allow concurrent access without blocking, and those allow for a lot of smart coding.

For the Array access there are two options: you can use an AtomicInteger as Index and have the threads `getAndIncremnt()` on this to get their working index. This is useful if you do know know how many threads you have or how long your data value is (hint: not really the case).

The second option is that you assign each thread a deterministic index from the beginning that ensures that no thread ever interferes with the others. If you i.E. have 4 threads and 256 data values, you could distribute the index values by an increment of 4. So Thread A gets 0, 4, 8, ... Thread B gets 1, 5, 9, ... and so on. This ensures that no thread will ever conflict with any other thread by design.

The counting at the end is equally easy: first have the thread count the words internally, then add the sum to a global AtomicInteger using `addAndGet()`.

Now you just need to figure out when to print the value. The answer is "When the last thread is done". This can be done - once again - using an AtomicInteger as a counter and have each thread `decrementAndGet()` and then check if they got a 0, which means they are the last thread and need to print the result. And then you could use a Barrier class, which will block, but at a point where it no longer matters, because all work is done at this point anyways.